# How to install missing material-ui files in react

Tags: reactjs

After having installed my `material-ui` for my react project, but when it comes to use it always bring up an **error** telling me that

> 'Module not found'
>
> ./src/Components/LatestPost.js`Module not found: Can't resolve`@material-ui/lab/Skeleton' in 'C:\Users\Zinox\super-surf\src\Components'

Answer (score 7):

You would have only installed `@material-ui/core` package which would not include the experimental features you are looking for and hence you are getting the error `Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton'`

To use experimental features of Material UI like Skeleton, Rating, Speed Dial and so on you need to also install the Material UI Lab package,

`npm install @material-ui/lab`

Note that this is needed in addition to the `@material-ui/core` package that you installed earlier with `npm install @material-ui/core`

After installing the above package you could import it as,

```
import Skeleton from '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton';
```

in your React Component and use it as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ramaraja it really help me

Answer (score 0):

you should add two packages into the app first is 
`yAR i @material-ui/lab  @material-ui/core`

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same issue. `Skeleton` doesn't seem to be contained in the latest package version (`4.0.0-alpha.22`) at the moment. But it is on their source folder, which is odd.

Maybe you open an issue at their [GitHub](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/).

EDIT:
I did: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16919

Answer (score 0):

**Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton'**

If you want to use Skeleton, Rating, Speed Dial, and so on you need to also install the Material UI **Lab** package.

```
npm install @material-ui/lab
```

or

```
yarn add @material-ui/lab
```

Link here.
[enter link description here](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/#installation)